# Using eof in my program and then continuously loops Why?

Tags: c++, while-loop, infinite-loop, eof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Here is my program it compiles and everything but the while loop with eof becomes infinite
the file scores.dat contains a list of 20 random numbers. Why does the eof not work and makes it loop continuously???

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

  int x, sum = 0, count = 0;
  double answer;
  ifstream  y;

  y.open("scores.dat");
  while (!y.eof())
   {
     y >> x;
     sum = sum + x;
     count ++;
     cout << x << endl;
   }

  answer = sqrt (((pow(x, 2.0)) - ((1.0/count) * (pow(x, 2.0)))) / (count - 1.0));
  cout << answer;

}
```

Comment: Here's another reason to never use `.eof()` as a loop condition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score 5):

EOF is not the only fail flag. If one of the others (such as the `fail` (to convert) flag) gets set then it's just going to loop round.

instead try this:

```
std::ifstream y("scores.dat");
while (y >> x) {
    sum += x;
    ++count;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

This is the idiomatic way to do this, the extractin operator return the a refrence to the stream, the stream evaluates as true so long as all it's fails bits are not set.

EDIT: Whilst I am here note the `+= operator` and constructor for `ifstream`.